# Installation Error regarding zzdb3 while installing MikTeX 21.2 x64 on windows 10 64-bit

Tags: errors, installing

**Error: Requested resource not found.**
**Details:**

**url:** https://ims.jit.ac.in/repo/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb3-2.9.tar.lzma

**GENERAL MIKTEX INFORMATION**
ReportDate: 2021-04-28 04:56:35
CurrentVersion: 21.2
SetupDate: 2021-04-28 04:51:00
**SetupVersion: 21.2**
Configuration: Regular
GitInfo: 7a7e645 / 2021-02-20 10:38:14
**OS: Windows 10 Home, 64-bit, build 19042**
**SharedSetup: yes**
**LinkTargetDirectory: D:\ProgramFiles\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64**
PathOkay: no
LastUpdateCheckAdmin: not yet
LastUpdateAdmin: not yet
LastUpdateDbAdmin: not yet
**SystemAdmin: yes**
**RootPrivileges: yes**
**AdminMode: yes**
**Root0: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX**
**Root1: D:\ProgramFiles\MiKTeX**
**CommonInstall: D:\ProgramFiles\MiKTeX**
**CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX**
**CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX**
**The following issues were detected:**
**  1: major issue: So far, no MiKTeX administrator has checked for updates.**

Comment: Can you install with Admin rights?

Comment: Why you don't want to install latest version of MikTeX (21.3)?